# subprocess can't get the stdin input from other process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I use `subprocess` exchange data between two process

I edit a `repeat.py` file with:

this file is a example from http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/

```
import sys

sys.stderr.write('repeater.py: starting\n')
sys.stderr.flush()

while True:
    next_line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not next_line:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(next_line)
    sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stderr.write('repeater.py: exiting\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
```

and run this file in `ipython`

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]:      f=subprocess.Popen(['python','~/repeat.py'],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [3]: f.stdin.write('teststs\n')

In [4]: f.communicate()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'teststs' is not defined
Out[4]: ('', None)
```

why `teststs` is not defined?

Comment: @Sven Marnach thanks for your comment ,it is runing ok after i remove `shell=True`

Comment: Fine – I turned the comment into an answer.

Comment: related: [Don't use a list argument together with shell=True in subprocess' docs](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be starting an interactive Python session instead of running `repeat.py`. Try removing `shell=True`, it doesn't make sense together with a list of parameters. (Using `shell=True` is almost always a bad idea, by the way.)

Answer (score -1):

This works with some strange behavior at first 5 key-presses. I don't know why. After that if works fine, and we have access to `ls -l`, `cd`, previous commands when press UP, seems command line has full functionality.

```
#!/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash'])
while True:
    buff = sys.stdin.readline()
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate(buff)
    if( stdoutdata ):
        print( stdoutdata )
    else:
        print('n')
        break
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140632/transparent-interaction-with-console-sh-bash-cmd-powershell) is my similar question.